# SSRS with MySQL Database

Tags: mysql, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

Basically, is this doable?

I have seen reports from both sides where some say it cannot be done, but then posts/blogs/etc that show a way to make it work.

My research has left me with too many questions to decide one way or another.

Can someone with experience in this area please advise or point me in the direction of some reliable information?

Apologies for such an open question, but my experience in this area is very lacking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am looking to do the same thing, and i did find this.  I have not tried it yet...

http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2615/creating-a-ssrs-report-using-a-mysql-data-source/

http://www.mazsoft.com/blog/post/2010/11/04/Using-SQL-Server-2008-Reporting-Services-(SSRS)-with-MySQL